# $n \in m \rightarrow n \subset m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We want to show that for ay natural numbers $m,n$ it stands that:

$$n \in m \rightarrow n \subset m$$

We define the set $X=\{ n \in \omega: \forall m (m \in n \rightarrow m \subset n)\}$.

It suffices to show that $X$ is an inductive set.

Could you explain me why this suffices?

Then, $\varnothing \in X$. Let $n \in X$.

We want to show that $n'=n \cup \{ n \} \in X$.

We take a $m \in n'$.

Then $m \in n$ or $m \in \{n\}$.

Do we have to show now that $m \subset n'$?

**EDIT**: The number $0$ is defined as the set $\varnothing$.
For each set $x$, with $x'$ we symbolize the set $x \cup \{ x \}$, i.e. $x'=x \cup \{ x \}$.
We define now $1=0'=\{ \varnothing \} \\ 2=1'= \{ \varnothing, \{ \varnothing \} \} \\ \dots$

A set $A$ is called inductive, if $\varnothing$ is an element of $A$ and for each $x \in A$, its next element $x'=x \cup \{ x \}$ belongs to $A$.

Comment: Your Question seems to be related to the definition of *ordinal numbers* in set theory, of which the finite sets may be identified with natural numbers.  However you have omitted the required definition of "natural numbers" that would allow one to prove anything about them.

Comment: @hardmath I edited my post.. Is it better now?

Comment: Thanks for editing your post.  You define set $X$ as a subset of $\omega$, presumably the set of finite (Von Neumann) [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), but you should make this explicit (if in fact the problem relies on that background).

Answer (score 1):

Sufficiency comes due to fact that set of natural numbers is least inductive set,meaning that it is subset of any inductive set.Then if your set X is inductive,then it has to contain every member of set of natural numbers,thus relation must hold for all natural numbers.

Comment: I understand... Could you also tell me how we can continue, in order to show that $X=\omega$ ?

Comment: Actually the proof you gave is the right one.You can proceed by usual induction.Claiming truth for 0,which is trivial to prove,then assume truth for some n,and then proceed to prove the truth for n+1,in exactly the manner you did.Namely by considering that $n+1=n \cup \{ n \}$

Comment: Could you explain me why, if we take a $m \in n'$ and we show that $m \subset n$, we have shown that $n' \in X$ ? :/